# How to get wordpress data feeds in xml format

Tags: php, wordpress, feed

I am developing wordpress site for newspaper. I want to send news feeds to mobile. I want to send these news feeds in xml format only. Currently, I am getting feeds in html format. How to get wordpress feeds in xml format?

Comment: How do you get HTML feeds from wordpress?

Comment: Html format means , feed gets open as a webpage.

Answer (score 0):

There is a built in feed in Wordpress that you can use.
I would recommend you to read up on https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds and try the examples to see if you can make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress creates an RSS feed in XML by default; this might appear to you as HTML when you view the RSS in a browser. View the page source to see the XML structure.

Get the feed programmatically (the DOM structure might be different in your instance):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://wordpress.example.com/feed/');
foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item) {
    print $item->title;
    print PHP_EOL;
}
```